# Return multiple columns with 3 distinct fields in SQL query for Access DB

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I am trying to make a query that returns multiple fields, keeping the first 3 as distinct columns and returns values for the last modified date. Some of the variables in the query fields should come from more than one table and one of them has a True/False criterion too. The three 3 distinct fields are needed because the combination of these is associated with the other returning parameters.

The tables look roughly as follows...

Table a:

```
 ID | Sc | Country | TechID | VarA | ... | VarX(T/F) | LastModified
  1 |  1 |    AA   |    1   |  x   | ... |     T     | 1-1-2017
  2 |  1 |    AA   |    1   |   z  | ... |     T     | 1-1-2017
  3 |  1 |    AA   |    2   |    y | ... |     T     | 1-1-2018
  4 |  1 |    AB   |    1   |   u  | ... |     T     | 1-1-2017
  5 |  2 |    AB   |    2   |   v  | ... |     T     | 1-1-2018
  6 |  3 |    AB   |    1   |   w  | ... |     F     | 1-1-2018
```

Table b:

```
TechID | TechName | Categ | Units
   1   |   Tech1  |  Cat1 | M
   2   |   Tech2  |  Cat2 | N
   3   |   Tech3  |  Cat3 | P
```

The idea is that the query returns something like this (when the T/F criterion is met). Where the combination of Sc-Country-Tech shows up only once, with the last modified having presedence:

```
Sc' | Country' |TechName'| Units | Cat | VarA... | LastModified | 
 1  |    AA    |    1    |  ...  | ... |   ...   | 1-1-2018
 1  |    AB    |    2    |  ...  | ... |   ...   | 1-1-2017
 2  |    AB    |    1    |  ...  | ... |   ...   | 1-1-2018
```

So far I've tried a few SQL lines to no avail. First, with Select DISTINCT but the option was too "all inclusive".

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Sc, a.Country, b.TechName, b.Units, b.Cat, a.VarA,..,a.VarX, Max(a.LastModified) AS MaxOfLastModified
FROM a INNER JOIN (b INNER JOIN a ON b.TechName = 
a.TechID) ON b.Cat = a.TechID
GROUP BY a.Sc, a.Country, b.TechName, b.Units, b.Cat, a.VarA,..,a.VarX
HAVING (((a.VarX)=True));
```

Also tried this but it prompts errors related to aggregate functions:

```
SELECT a.Sc, a.Country, b.TechID, b.Units, b.Cat, a.VarA,..,a.VarX, Max(a.LastModified) AS MaxOfLastModified
FROM a INNER JOIN (b INNER JOIN a ON b.TechName = 
a.TechID) ON b.Cat = a.TechID
GROUP BY a.Sc, a.Country, a.TechID
HAVING (((a.VarX)=True));
```

Any thoughts/suggestions on how to go about this?? Any pointers to previous related answers are also much appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

---

***EDIT*** (2017.09.29):

This certainly cleared things up a bit!

I managed to get the query going with some of the fields, only when calling fields from a single table with the following:

```
SELECT a.Sc, a.Country, a.Tech, a.LastModified, a.VarA
FROM a INNER JOIN (SELECT Sc, Country, Tech, max(LastModified) AS lm FROM a GROUP BY Sc, Country, Tech)  AS dt ON (dt.lm=a.LastModified) AND (dt.Tech=a.Tech) AND (dt.Country=a.Country) AND (dt.Sc=a.Sc)
GROUP BY a.Sc, a.Country, a.Tech, a.LastModified, a.VarA, a.VarX
HAVING (((a.VarX)=Yes));
```

I'm still running into a syntax error on JOIN when trying to add fields from a lookup table using the INNER JOIN command as suggested. The code I tried looked something like:

```
SELECT a.Sc, a.Country, a.Tech, a.LastModified, a.VarA b.TechCategory
FROM a INNER JOIN (SELECT Sc, Country, Tech, max(LastModified) AS lm FROM a GROUP BY Sc, Country, Tech)  AS dt ON (dt.lm=a.LastModified) AND (dt.Tech=a.Tech) AND (dt.Country=a.Country) AND (dt.Sc=a.Sc)
INNER JOIN b ON Tech.Category=a.Tech
GROUP BY a.Sc, a.Country, a.Tech, b.TechCategory, a.LastModified, a.VarA, a.VarX
HAVING (((a.VarX)=Yes));
```

Any additional pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: In your edit, the join to table `b` does not reference table `b`, but it references `Tech.Category`, and `Tech` is not a defined table or alias, and `Category` is not a column of the example tables `a` and `b`.  In the same join, the column `a.Tech` does not exist in your example table.  Either your examples are not accurate, or the code has typographical or logical errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregate query to get the maximum date for each combination of `Sc`, `Country`, and `TechID`, then use this as a subquery and join it back to tables `a` and `b` to get the data in your final query.  Something like this:

```
select
    a.Sc, a.Country, b.TechName,
    b.Units, b.Category, b.Units, a.VarA, a.LastModified
from
    (Table_a as a
    inner join (
        select   Sc, Country, TechID, max(LastModified) as lm
        from     Table_a
        group by Sc, Country, TechID
        ) as dt on dt.Sc=a.Sc and dt.Country=a.Country and dt.TechID=a.TechID and dt.lm=a.LastModified)
    inner join Table_b as b on b.TechID=a.TechID
```

Comment: This certainly cleared things up a bit. I managed to get the query going with fields from a single table. The query is still running into a syntax error on JOIN when trying to add fields from a lookup table using the second INNER JOIN command as suggested. I'm expanding on the new code as an edit on my original question.